MYSQL query to UPDATE column with value in different column of different record possibly using subquery
I am very rusty on MYSQL and having trouble updating columns based on a different column in a different record. I'm thinking I need to do a subquery but would appreciate help in how to do this.
The table being queried is an aggregate of other tables where the letters represent the table and the number the id in that table. Here is a simplified version. I realize this structure seems a bit clunky but it can't be changed.
  Posts
    id|text
    1|The Foo Fighters may be going on tour

    Comments
    
    (parentid is what the comment is on. If comment is on a previous
comment than grandparentid is what the previous comment referenced.
     
    id|parentid|grandparentid|text
    
    1|post-1|NULL|Who cares
    2|comment-1|post-1|What do you mean who cares. That's awesome.
    3|comment-2|NULL|Have they set dates?

There are a lot of records such as 3 where the grandparentid is blank though it can be figured out as it is the parent in turn of the parent comment(eg comment 2).
How can I update all of the grandparentid of Record 3 where we know commentid of the parent and the parent has a parent.
I believe it is something like the following but would appreciate any validation or correction as I don't want to run the query and potentially mess up the data Thanks for any guidance or suggestions.
UPDATE comments `c` 
SET grandparentid = (SELECT parentid FROM comments `co` WHERE co.id = c.parentid)
WHERE grandparentid IS NULL

Edit
Above code with = NULL changed to IS NULL as per Wilmm gives MYSQL error

You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause

thinking of trying following but worried it will mess up table.  MYSQL says it can't roll it back...
UPDATE comments `c`
    SET c.grandparentid = co.parentid
LEFT JOIN comments `co` ON co.id=c.parentid
    WHERE c.grandparentid IS NULL;

Edit:
Following Query runs without error but does not change any rows... Not sure what it is doing
UPDATE comments `c` 
LEFT JOIN comments `co` 
ON c.parentid = co.id 
SET c.grandparentid = co.parentid 
WHERE c.grandparentid IS NULL


not WHERE grandparentid = NULL, but WHERE grandparentid is NULL

By fact posts and comments does not differ - both are messages which may be either initial message or reply message. So they'd be stored in ONE self-referenced table.

Hi I think you need to try with an inner join update like so:
update comments com
    set com.grandparentid = com_p.parentid
inner join comments com_p on com_p.id=com.parentid
    where com.grandparentid is null;


tnx for the correction :)
